# Objective-C: My init values aren't being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, initialization, spritebuilder

I been pulling my hair out over this, I can't seem to figure this simple issue out.

I have a class which extends CCNode, here's the header:

```
#import "CCNode.h"

@interface ContentPane : CCNode

@property (nonatomic, strong) CCNode * _rockPath1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCNode * _rockPath2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCNode *_secondPath1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCNode *_secondPath2;

@property (nonatomic) int map;

-(void)generatePane;

@end
```

I am trying to initialize this class so that the visibility of _rockPath1, _rockPath2, etc is hidden. However, the values I set in at init aren't being respected. Here's my init, in my init I'm simply trying to set the position of ._rockPath1 because I know that line of code works because I have it elsewhere in my program and it works fine.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.map = 0x11111111;
    CCLOG(@"WHAT");
    //_rockPath1.position = ccp(90,90);
    self._rockPath1.position = ccp(90,90);
    return self;
}
```

After my class is initialized, _rockPath1 does not have the position I set for it, it still has the values defined in SpriteBuilder. Strangely enough, map is set to the correct values, but the position is not.

Comment: I think you should not extend this class with ccnode if you are creating instances inside this ContentPane. And also during init you need to allocate memory to _ rockpath1 before assigning position to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you are using SpriteBuilder, and assuming you make the assignments to `_rockPath` etc from SpriteBuilder (doc root var), you have to do the initialization of the default values in `didLoadFromCCB` (and remove your init method):

```
-(void) didLoadFromCCB 
{
    self.map = 0x11111111;
    _rockPath1.position = ccp(90,90);
}
```

The thing is, the init method runs the instance the node is created which means it runs way before the assignments from CCBReader will be applied.